# PHP cURL works with XML, Cross-Domain Ajax fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I am trying to request data from an server. The server needs the request in the xml-format. The following PHP-Function works just fine, as it is the server side.
XML_POST_URL is the url I am posting to, $xml I am sending.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close', 'Content-Type: text/xml'));
```

However, if I try to archieve the same with JavaScript, it fails. For now I am starting Chrome with

> --disable-web-security

which disables the Cross-Domain-Policy. Later the app will be deployed on a device via Cordova. Anyhow the following AJAX-Request fails:

```
$.ajax({
    url: XML_POST_URL,
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    crossDomain: true,
    processData: false,
    data: xml
    }).done(function(jqXhr){
        console.log(jqXhr);
    }).fail(function(jqXhr){
        console.log(jqXhr);
    });
```

The error I get from the serverside states, that the XML is wrongly formated. Now I am wondering were exatcly the difference between the server side curl and the client side ajaxcall is (remember the cross domain policy is disabled)? Is the Ajax-Call somehow manipulating the XML?

EDIT:
Here is the XML-Error I get from the Server:

```
<ResC xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="No path to XML scheme defined"
ver="1.1" prod="String" lang="EN"><Err code="P2" text="invalid xml
document: xmlDocument must begin with "<?xml>" or "xml=<?xml>""
level="E"/></ResC>
```

EDIT2:
Here is the content of the xml-variable (its copied from the working php snippet):

```
    var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><ReqC lang="DE" prod="testsystem" ver="1.1" accessId="myID"><ConReq><Start><Station externalId="9470098" /><Prod prod="1111000000000000" direct="0" /></Start><Dest><Station externalId="9470101" /></Dest><ReqT a="0" date="20121207" time="11:57" /><RFlags b="0" f="6" sMode="N" /></ConReq></ReqC>'
```

Solution:

It turned out, that using the Ripple emulator was a bad idea, as it was wrapping something around the request somehow. If run in a "pure" chrome, it worked!

Comment: Have you looked at the xml being sent by the ajax request?

Comment: Do you mean the xml variable or the content of the variable I would get if I use var x = $.ajax({}); ?

Comment: The actual string being sent in the http request.

Comment: The variable xml looks fine, if that is what you aiming at.

Comment: See the full error in my original question

Comment: What is the content of the variable `xml`?

Comment: look at the network tab in the chrome inspector. what is the response from the server when requesting with chrome?

Comment: That was the hint I needed. Turned out, that it is not a good idea to use Ripple (which I used to emulate device). The emulator seems to wrap my request. If run in a "pure" chrome, it works.